# Matching part of Excel column to another and pasting a set of values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns

I have a long column in an Excel spreadsheet that I'd like to match with another long column in the same sheet.

The columns look like:

[image]

And I want to make a script that will allow me to check **A to F** using **B to copy and paste** F,G,H to B,C,D if A and F match to look like:

[image]

The problem is that A and F don't usually match exactly; only most of the words - as you can see with "metal corp & company" vs "metal corp".
Is there any way I can do this via script? I know I can see if they match exactly using something like `=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$F$2:$F$5, 0)))` etc....Or to explicitly state the name in quotations, but nothing to match only part of the entry to another.

Also, is there any way to automatically paste F,G,H if the match is found?

Comment: any reason not to use a vlookup and not paste actual values?

Comment: Not sure how to do that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you can do a vlookup and break the formula with copy/paste values if needed. you may not need to do that.

So, you need to consider how to make vlookup work. vlookup can take a value and search for it in an array and return a corresponding value in that row of the array that it is found. given your ask for the following values along the right, this should work well if we can get a value to be matched. afterwards just repeat the same formula with +1 to each column being returned (F, G, H).

So, your issue is getting the match to work since you think most of the time the values do not match 100%, but are close. you need to make them match, somehow. either by manually assigning an lookup table where the alias's are aligned. e.g. on another sheet, in column A, have "metal corp & company" and in column b, have "metal corp" or by a formula to establish a match. depending on the number of rows, doing it manually may be substantially less work than a formula. a formula can work it the alias's are consistently wrong in a certain fashion. if it is random, then a formula won't work.

I would try something as simple =vlookup(value,array,column,TRUE). the true value will return an approximate match instead of exact match.

See example screenshot, the only formula is in column B. "hi" is close enough to "high" and then "there" is returned from column e.

[image]